# LINQ to SQL -- Same User Object, different data context

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a user object called UserSystem, which is created by a static factory class that returns User Systems.  Because the factory class only exists to create this object once, then disposes, is it possible to associate my persisted UserSystem object with another instance of my database context that I create at a later point?

I would like to avoid having to query my new DatabaseContext to find the matching UserSystem object and simply associate the persisted user object from the first DatabaseContext class with my new DatabaseContext.

Thanks!
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to Attach your object to the DataContext. There are many articles about this, for example [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2007/10/08/attach-if-you-have-something-detached.aspx). Be careful though - this method is not intended to allow you to attach objects that are already attached to another DataContext, it is only for deserialized objects that are completely unattached, which I assume is what you have.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `Attach` method on the `Table<T>` object to insert a detached data object into it. You may insert it in a modified state, or in an unmodified state. If you insert it in a modified state, the next `SubmitChanges()` call will include it.

[The Table(Of TEntity) Attach method overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548978.aspx)